# How do I cancel a pipeline that is waiting on a manual trigger?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I used the starter template when starting to create a pipeline:

```
# This is an example Starter pipeline configuration
# Use a skeleton to build, test and deploy using manual and parallel steps
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.

image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          name: 'Build and Test'
          script:
            - echo "Your build and test goes here..."
      - step:
          name: 'Lint'
          script:
            - echo "Your linting goes here..."
      - step:
          name: 'Security scan'
          script:
            - echo "Your security scan goes here..."

    # The following deployment steps will be executed for each pipeline run. To configure your steps and conditionally deploy see https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment to Staging'
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - echo "Your deployment to staging script goes here..."
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment to Production'
        deployment: production
        trigger: 'manual'
        script:
          - echo "Your deployment to production script goes here..."
```

When running this pipeline it waits for the manual trigger stage:

[image]

I don't want to run that stage and want to just cancel the pipeline, but I cannot find any button in the UI to do that. It's currently hanging in the "IN_PROGRESS" state which I don't want because I plan on filtering pipelines by state for other purposes. How do I just cancel this?

Can pipelines be set to cancel automatically after a certain time?

### Edit

I tried to `rerun` and then immediately stop it, but the run is still there as `Paused`. So it's not `In progress`, but it's still just hanging out there. Also, while the UI does not show it's in progress the `state` as returned by the `/pipelines/` GET endpoint looks like this:

```
  "state": {
    "name": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "type": "pipeline_state_in_progress",
    "stage": {
      "name": "PAUSED",
      "type": "pipeline_state_in_progress_paused"
    }
  },
```

Is there no way to just remove and clean up this run?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to start it and then immediately stop it. The pipeline would show as stopped.

The worker waiting time plus the setup phase are usually slow enough so that your pipeline step script would not even start.

Yet, keep in mind that the deploy steps can be individually redeployed and the full pipeline can be re-run. So you can't effectively irreversibly cancel that pipeline in a way that it can't be deployed to production in any future.

Comment: You mean `rerun` and then stop? I did that but its still there as "paused". Adding EDIT comment to my question. Is there a way to just like remove it?

Comment: I mean to start the next manual step, the one paused, and stop it before it really runs.

Comment: Whoops I misunderstood! I just didn't that and it "worked". thanks!

Comment: Just noting that this is risky as a solution, particularly in the example where this is triggering a deploy to production - as you are counting on the delay in the pipeline running and the speed of your clicking to ensure nothing runs.